# Not able to read complete cookie in perl

Tags: perl, cookies

I am receiving below cookie from my source system

```
ExternalAccess=unixtime=1593603710&oracletime=01-jul-20 
12:41:50_Hash_thNnmggU2ex3L5XXeMNfxf8Wl8STcVZTxscSFEKSxa0
```

At destination system [PERL based], using below code to read the cookie

```
my $extSysCookie = $Query->cookie('ExternalAccess');
```

i am getting below output

```
External Access cookie = unixtime=1593603710
```

and not able to read full value.All characters after & are getting omitted. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this CGI.pm?

Comment: `printf("key:%s val:%s\n", $_, $Query->cookie($_)) for $Query->cookie;`

Comment: Please show minimal, complete examples that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @simbabque  Yes, its an CGI.pm,  Tried Printf option  got this value only key:ExternalAccess val:unixtime=1593663450  , where as complete value for ExternalAccess in cookie is "unixtime=1593603710&oracletime=01-jul-20 
12:41:50_Hash_thNnmggU2ex3L5XXeMNfxf8Wl8STcVZTxscSFEKSxa0"   . Its not taking the values after & symbol

Comment: @Сухой27 :  Tried Printf option got this value only key:ExternalAccess val:unixtime=1593663450 , where as complete value for ExternalAccess in cookie is "unixtime=1593603710&oracletime=01-jul-20 12:41:50_Hash_thNnmggU2ex3L5XXeMNfxf8Wl8STcVZTxscSFEKSxa0" . Its not taking the values after & symbol

Comment: Since cookie is in non standard format, you can parse it manually after retrieving raw content, `https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#raw_cookie()`

Comment: CGI's `->cookie` splits the cookies values on `/[&;]/` and uri-decodes the resulting values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's not a valid cookie. Spaces are not allowed in the value of cookies. [Ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2).

Secondly, that's not a correctly formatted cookie for CGI.pm's `->cookie`. `->cookie` is designed to handle cookies created using CGI.pm's `->cookie`. The cookie value in question was not created with that method, and the cookie can't be handled (correctly) by that method.

To get the desired string from `->cookie`, either construct the cookie using `->cookie`, or otherwise create a cookie with the URI-encoding the value you wish `->cookie` to return.

For example, the desired string will be returned for a cookie with the value

```
unixtime%3D1593603710%26oracletime%3D01-jul-20%2012%3A41%3A50_Hash_thNnmggU2ex3L5XXeMNfxf8Wl8STcVZTxscSFEKSxa0
```

CGI's approach allows cookies to have multiple values, and gets around the problem of spaces being forbidden in the values of cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   i didnt put the complete cookie bcz of security reasons and tried to add a sample one. Since cookie contains key value pair, externalAccess was one of the key and string which i pasted above was value. However, we have resolved this by replacing "&" with "/" in value string and then we were able to read the complete value of the parameter in cookie..

Comment: That's not good enough; it won't always work. Again, if you want to use `->cookie`, you need to create the cookie using `->cookie` or uri-encode the desied value of the cookie if you craft it by some other means.